# Django page not loaded with exception 'bytes' object is not callable issue

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm doing downloading of the file in Django. I have added path into urls.py and in views.py trying to make code which will be loading a file and render page.

```
def download(request):

    render(request, 'personal/home.html') # seems that it doesn't work

    filename = "C:/some_path/test_file.txt"
    wrapper = FileWrapper(open(filename))
    response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='text/plain')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % os.path.basename(filename)
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(filename)
    return response
```

As the result I got:

> Exception Type:   TypeError
>
> Exception Value: 'bytes' object is not callable

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove this line:

```
render(request, 'personal/home.html')
```